# Run suite of suites using argumentfile option

Tags: robotframework

I have two suite files, `child1, child2` each having multiple test cases under them. Now, i have a top file called as `master-suite` that has two lines - `child1` and `child2`, indicating that it needs to run those two suites.

But running,

```
pybot --argumentfile master-suite
```

throws error as,

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing '/home/sk/master-suite' failed: Unsupported file format ''.
```

I have hundreds of test cases and i would like to group them under different features and keep them in smaller files. And maintain one master suite of all child suites.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

`child1` and `child2` are invalid filenames for robot suite files. You will get exactly the same error if you tried to run the files individually with `pybot child1`.

Robot uses the suffix to know how to parse the file. If you give the files a suffix such as `.txt` or `.robot`, and modify your argument file accordingly, it should work fine.

That being said, if they are in a folder, you can give the folder as an argument to robot and it will run all tests in that folder without the need of an argument file:

```
pybot master-suite
```

Comment: Bryan, child1 is not a testcase file. It is a suite file, that has two more robot cases written inside it. When i renamed c to c.robot and ran, it threw error as, `Parsing '/home/sk/c.robot' failed: File has no test case table`

Comment: @MadhavanKumar: yes, I understand child1 is a suite file. It must have a proper suffix. As you see, when you added the suffix the problem went away. The new problem is unrelated to the first. The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you don't have a test case table.