# Parsing failed: Unsupported file format 'py'

Tags: python, eclipse, robotframework, pydev

I’m trying to run some robot framework tests in eclipse. I have Python, PyDev, Robot Framework (and all other things which I need) already installed, but it comes always the same error message "Parsing failed: Unsupported file format 'py'". Does anyone know where the problem may lie? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You will get this exact error if you tell robot to run a file as if it was a test case (e.g. `robot something.py`). The solution is pretty simple: don't pass a .py file as an argument to robot.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell what did you try until now ? i cant comment that's why i ll write my Comments here. I think it have something to do with filenames. Maybe you gave a filename to robot, and robot can't find that file.

Maybe it also means :

- the file does not exist. For example, maybe you forgot to save the file
- you misspelled the filename
- you spelled the filename correct, the file exists, but it is in a different directory than the current working directory.

here is some Question that maybe will help you if you have the same Problem:
[Run suite of suites using argumentfile option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637033/run-suite-of-suites-using-argumentfile-option)

Comment: That error message doesn't mean any of the things you listed. In all of those cases you would get a different error message.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok but actually in those cases that I mentionned i got the same Error "Parsing failed: Unsupported file format 'py' so i thought i share that with him.